# Растянуть пункты меню по всей ширине BottomAppBar

Tags: android, android-layout

Доброго времени суток: как сделать что бы пункты меню в BottomAppBar были расположены по всей ширине компонента.
Сейчас это выглядит почему то вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должно вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:backgroundTint="#FFF"
            app:buttonGravity="center_vertical"
            app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation" />


        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:src="@drawable/floating_action_button"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="center" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Как можно это поправить?

Comment: Попробуйте [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58515876/3212712) - перенести меню в BottomNavigationView, который надо поместить внутрь BottomAppBar

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо, помогло)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:backgroundTint="#FFF"
            app:buttonGravity="center_vertical"
            app:fabAlignmentMode="center" >
            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
                app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation"/>
        </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:src="@drawable/floating_action_button"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="center" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```